# How get module interface from *.pyd?

Tags: python, c++, boost, interface, pyd

I generated *.pyd file using `boost python` and copy this file to the `C:\Python27\DLLs\`

Now I want to get interface module. PyCharm can generate this interface using own tool. Header module's interface:

```
# encoding: utf-8
# module my_module
# from C:\Python27\DLLs\my_module.pyd
# by generator 1.136
```

How can I generate this interface without PyCharm?
Thank you!